# Memory Stream vs File Stream for static content download

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, algorithm

I have a scenario that every file uploaded that may be of any MIME type should be encrypted and when use wants to download they should be decrypted.

For this I have decrypted a requested file and saved that file in a temporary location.
My decryption method writes to a filestream by reading encrypted filestream.

Now should I change my algorithm to save encrypted filestream to a memory stream
and download directly from memory stream instead of writing to filestream and downloading that file.

In term of performance which would be better filestream or memory stream in this case.

I am thinking that if multiple huge file is requested by multiple users lets say 100 different files are requested by 100 different users. In this case memory may run out and we may face some unwanted troubles.

Which one I should implement.

Comment: Have you considered using something like EFS instead, where on-disk encryption is handled higher-up in the IO chain? That way you don't need to concern your application logic with file encryption.

Comment: @Dai I am unaware of EFS. Thanks for the info I will consult about this with sysadmin and look for the possibilities for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered streaming directly into the `NetworkStream` for output? You will need no memory and no disc space for that. If you expect higher performance from buffering the data in a `BufferedStream` as an intermediate.

If direct or buffered streaming is not an option for you, the correct answer depends on your requirements. You need to know the size of your files and the expected  umber of requests. If you think your web servers memory can handle it and you need the added performance, go for it. Otherwise you should buffer on the hard drive. Remember: you only need *sufficient* performance, not *perfect* performance.

Comment: `NetworkStream` is not an option for me. 
Currently we are allowing only limited size file (less than 50MB) and we expect less than 100 request per hour for file. In this case our server can handle this. Thus, should I go for MemoryStream.